# SQL Server Group By Help Required

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Being a beginner, how can I get results as mentioned in the diagram. I am not getting results by grouping. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Ali, which database are you using. This can be accomplished through `Pivot` if your database supports it. Also take a look at this link, it will help you understand how to transpose the data (get those Queries sums into columns) once you have aggregated it.
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/using-row-numbering-and-full-joins-to-transpose-wide-tables.html

Comment: Post a SQL Fiddle link and someone can help you with the code.

Comment: Most of users prefer formatted text instead of images, please do not post your code, sample data, as images..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your example data correctly, it *seems* that for Query3, you have the data flip-flopped for the dates.  I think Query3 elapsed for 10/20/2017 should be 2:03 and for 10/21/2017, the elapsed time should be 1:48.

If that is indeed the case, here is a solution that uses a combination of [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx), aggregation and [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).  It works for the example data you've provided in your question.  You may need to adjust it for other data.

```
set nocount on
Declare @t Table (ID int, [Date] Date, ExecutedTime varchar(10), Label Varchar(10))
insert into @t values
(1,'2017-10-20','0:01:16','Query1'),
(2,'2017-10-20','0:00:20','Query1'),
(3,'2017-10-20','0:00:14','Query1'),
(4,'2017-10-20','0:01:43','Query2'),
(5,'2017-10-20','0:00:33','Query2'),
(6,'2017-10-20','0:00:34','Query2'),
(7,'2017-10-20','0:01:18','Query3'),
(8,'2017-10-20','0:00:30','Query3'),
(9,'2017-10-20','0:00:15','Query3'),
(10,'2017-10-21','0:01:16','Query1'),
(11,'2017-10-21','0:00:20','Query1'),
(12,'2017-10-21','0:00:14','Query1'),
(13,'2017-10-21','0:01:43','Query2'),
(14,'2017-10-21','0:00:33','Query2'),
(15,'2017-10-21','0:00:34','Query2'),
(16,'2017-10-21','0:01:18','Query3'),
(16,'2017-10-21','0:00:30','Query3')
;
With ExecutedTimeInSeconds as   --Convert ExecutedTime to seconds in preparation for aggregation
(
select 
    [Date],
    Label,
    datepart(hour,(convert(time,executedTime))) * 3600 +
    datepart(minute,(convert(time,executedTime))) * 60 +  
    datepart(second,(convert(time,executedTime))) as ElapsedSeconds
from @t
)
,AggregatedDataInElapsedSeconds as --Aggregate the seconds by Date and Label
(
SELECT [Date]
    ,Label
    ,sum(ElapsedSeconds) AS ElapsedSeconds
FROM ExecutedTimeInSeconds
GROUP BY [Date]
    ,Label
),
DataReadyForPivot as    --Convert the aggregageted seconds back to an elapsed time
(
SELECT [Date], Label,
RIGHT('0' + CAST(ElapsedSeconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((ElapsedSeconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(ElapsedSeconds % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as ExecutedSum
from AggregatedDataInElapsedSeconds
)
,
PivotedData as  --Pivot the data
(
SELECT *
FROM DataReadyForPivot
PIVOT(MAX(ExecutedSum) FOR Label IN (
            [Query1]
            ,[Query2]
            ,[Query3]
            )) AS pvt
)
select --add a row number as Id
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Date] desc) as Id,
    *
from PivotedData
```

---

```
| Id | Date       | Query1   | Query2   | Query3   |
|----|------------|----------|----------|----------|
| 1  | 2017-10-21 | 00:01:50 | 00:02:50 | 00:01:48 |
| 2  | 2017-10-20 | 00:01:50 | 00:02:50 | 00:02:03 |
```